# Nested Field Gives TypeError upon indexing in elasticsearch-dsl-py

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

Whenever i try to save an object that has a nested field i get a Type error.

`TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types`

I have following document classes:

```
class CreationIndex(InnerDoc):

    created_by = Keyword()
    created_date = Date()

class UpdationIndex(InnerDoc):

    updated_by = Keyword()
    updated_date = Date()

class IndustryIndex(DocType):
    name = Text(analyzer= 'english')
    creation = CreationIndex()
    updation = Nested(UpdationIndex())

    class Meta:
        index = 'industry'

def bulk_indexing():

    elastic_connection = Elasticsearch(hosts=['localhost'], timeout=20)
    if elastic_connection.indices.exists('industry'):
        elastic_connection.indices.delete('industry')
    if elastic_connection.indices.exists('category'):
        elastic_connection.indices.delete('category')

    IndustryIndex.init()
    print('HI')
    bulk(client=elastic_connection, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Industry.objects.all()))
```

My Industry Model is a django model (where i have used mongoDB so itself is a dynamic document) which is defined as

```
class Industry(DynamicDocument,BaseCreationUpdation):
    name=StringField(required=True,unique=True)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        '''
        '''
        self=save_created_updated_info(self)
        super(Industry,self).save(args,kwargs)

    def indexing(self):
        objCreation = CreationIndex(
            created_by = self.creation.created_by,
            created_date = self.creation.created_date.date().isoformat()
            )
        print(objCreation.to_dict())
        obj = IndustryIndex(
            meta = {'id': str(self.id)},
            name = self.name,
            creation = objCreation.to_dict(),
            updation = [],
            )

        for objUp in self.updation:

            objUpdation = UpdationIndex(
                updated_by = objUp.updated_by,
                updated_date = objUp.updated_date.date().isoformat()
                )
            print(objUpdation)
            obj.updation.append(objUpdation)
            print()
            print(obj.to_dict())
            print()
        obj.save()

        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)

    @classmethod
    def index_document(cls,sender, document, **kwargs):
        document.indexing()
```

Now whenever i run the bulk_indexing module it comes up with a problem :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\projects\django\bhetincha\category\search.py", line 57, in bulk_indexing
    bulk(client=elastic_connection, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Industry.objects.all()))
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\__init__.py", line 257, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\__init__.py", line 180, in streaming_bulk
    client.transport.serializer):
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\helpers\__init__.py", line 58, in _chunk_actions
    for action, data in actions:
  File "D:\projects\django\bhetincha\category\search.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
    bulk(client=elastic_connection, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Industry.objects.all()))
  File "D:\projects\django\bhetincha\category\models.py", line 80, in indexing
    obj.save()
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\document.py", line 405, in save
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\utils.py", line 417, in full_clean
    self.clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\utils.py", line 403, in clean_fields
    data = field.clean(data)
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\field.py", line 179, in clean
    data = super(Object, self).clean(data)
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\field.py", line 90, in clean
    data = self.deserialize(data)
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\field.py", line 81, in deserialize
    for d in data
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\field.py", line 81, in <listcomp>
    for d in data
  File "C:\Users\prabi\Envs\bhetincha\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch_dsl\field.py", line 160, in _deserialize
    if isinstance(data, self._doc_class):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

Why is there this error? When i removed the updation filed which is nested it all works, though the creation field is the same. Whats the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

The way you are initialising the nested field is wrong - you need to pass a class rather than an instance of the class as the argument to the constructor (i.e., drop the brackets):

```
updation = Nested(UpdationIndex)  # Instead of Nested(UpdationIndex())
```